# How to slide multiple images with left and right arrows in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a collection grid of 10 movie items per row. I'm looking to find a way to slide through this grid horizontally with arrows on the right and left end, just like netflix grids. Is there any easy way to do this?

https://i.ibb.co/VJ52mg2/Screenshot-27.png

```
<div className="collection-preview">
<h1 className="title">{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
  <div className="preview"> 
  {     
        movies
        ? (movieData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }
  {
        tvshow
        ? (tvData.map(({id, ...otherProps}) => <CollectionItem key={id} {...otherProps} />))
        : null
  }

  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Look here for examples https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it from scratch, try [react-responsive-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive-carousel)

Here is a [demo](http://react-responsive-carousel.js.org/#demos)

Remove the images and add whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try React-Multi-Carousel,

Npm install it, npm i react-multi-carousel

Check this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel

Answer (score 0):

There are n number of react libraries are available. Here I have listed some libraries,

**React slick**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick

try the demo link,
[click here](https://react-slick.neostack.com/)

**React Multi Carousel**

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-carousel

try the demo link for image and video, [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2omn67p8kj)

try this demo link for custom elements, [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pg4fj)

Hope it was helpful for you :)